# Get Stun info with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, stun

I tried to get external ip & port with Python

I use: `pip install pystun`

```
import stun
stun.get_ip_info()
```

But I got error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 252, in get_ip_info
    nat_type, nat = get_nat_type(s, source_ip, source_port,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 186, in get_nat_type
    _initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/stun/__init__.py", line 93, in _initialize
    dictValToAttr.update({items[i][1]: items[i][0]})
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not tech support. Questions like this are best answered by *reading the documentation*. Before installing anything with `pip`, the first documentation you should check is [the PyPI page for the package](https://pypi.org/project/pystun/), which among other things will tell you which versions of Python are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `pystun` is out of date. `pystun` does not support recent version of python. Instead, install pystun3

```
pip uninstall pystun # uninstall already installed pystun module
pip install pystun3
```

```
import stun
print(stun.get_ip_info())
#('Symmetric NAT', '111.111.11.111', 1027)
```

Or, you can get your external IP address, as follows:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ifconfig.me")
conn.request("GET", "/ip")
print(conn.getresponse().read())
```

For more information, see https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/133137/

Comment: Thank you , with `ifconfig.me` I can get only external IP

Answer (score 2):

The original Pystun does not [support](https://github.com/jtriley/pystun/issues/21) Python 3. There is a [fork](https://github.com/a7md0/pystun) that supports Python 3 which you can install using `pip install pystun3` ([pystun3](https://pypi.org/project/pystun3/) on Pypi).